# Delete FloatingActionButton from Settings Page Only

Tags: android, application-settings, floating-action-button, navigation-drawer

So I recently implemented a navigation drawer in my app. Along with Navigation drawer I also implemented menu items to access options like settings. However, I want to keep this floating action button on all the Navigation drawer pages but I don't want to have it on my settings page which is accessed from menu. Here is the current code that I have.

The on create for the nav bar.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    //.setAction("Action", null).show();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Then this is the code for the floating action button itself in the app_bar_nav_drawer.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi.NavDrawerActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_nav_drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_share"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code for the settings_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:text="Use Cell Data to retrieve driving data:"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/cast_expanded_controller_background_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Enable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="Disable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true" />
    </RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Just an FYI I want to keep this for the menu pages only, not the settings page. Let me know if I can add anymore code that would help.

Entire Nav Drawer Activity

```
    public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        //.setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentSettingsManager = getFragmentManager();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            fragmentSettingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.speed_graph);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.drive_player);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go Check Out All Driving Data in the Play Store!");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update the code of navigation item selected method, changes must be made there.

Comment: @MohammedAtif, I have added where I select the settings button. I think that is what you were asking for correct?

Comment: yes exactly, i will post the answer by making changes to your code

Answer (score 0):

You could add "fab.setVisibility(View.GONE)" to the OnCreate only in those Activities where it should be hidden

Hope this helped

Comment: very bad suggestion. He will waste his time by solving nullpointerexception with your procedure.

Comment: If he uses this after the LayoutInflater it should work fine

Comment: One thing you must remember is `fab` is variable in main class. Accessing it or modifying it from other classes is possible but absolutely not recommended.

Comment: But if the button exists in every Activity he can use the same `FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab); ` in any Activity.

Comment: I suggest your to read navigation drawer implementation again. We preferably use fragments for drawers, and use single FAB overlaying on all the fragments which is controlled by main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to handle such cases using interfaces.
So first create an interface.

FabVisibilityController.java

```
public interface FabVisiblityController{
   toggleVisibility(boolean visibility);
}
```

Then in your main class

NavigationDrawerActivity.java

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, FabVisibilityController{
    //write this code at the end of the class
    @override
    toggleVisibility(boolean visibility){
         if(visibility)
             fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         else
             fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

then in your settings fragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment{
    Context context;
    FabVisibilityController controller;
    //then in onAttach method
    @override
    onAttach(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        if(context instanceof FabVisibilityController)
              controller = (FabVisibilityController) context;
    }

    //then in onResume Method
    @override
    onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //this will hide FAB whenever settings page is called
        controller.toggleVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

Do the same in your other fragments, but only difference will be, `controller.toggleVisibility(true)` should be called in `onResume()` to make FAB visible.

Comment: What would I put "anything else" to? The id of the fab?

Comment: No, ID of your remaining drawer items.

Comment: Anything other than settings should have `fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` otherwise your fab button will not reappear when you come to other pages.

Comment: But my selection of menu items is separate from the selecting of the settings button. Furthermore, it highlights fab in red in the fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: I have added the entire drawer activity so you can take a look at what I mean.

Comment: I am glad that you get it. I am still a little confused.

Comment: Ok just so have this correctly, I make a java file under Java that is FabVisibilityController, then in my nav drawer activity, I put what you put at the bottom, and the code for the settings fragment in that java file? However, I am not sure about the onResume() part as I don't have those.

Comment: You can always override `onResume()` method, but dont forget to make a call to to `super.onResume()` it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found best for me

```
@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            FragmentManager fragmentSettingsManager = getFragmentManager();
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                fragmentSettingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();
                setTitle(R.string.speed_graph);
                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();
                setTitle(R.string.drive_player);
                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
                setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go Check Out All Driving Data in the Play Store!");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
            }
```

Comment: Did it work when you come back to normal page from settings page?

Comment: @MohammedAtif yes it does, due to the `View.VISIBLE` in each one. The only thing I have troubles with is going back to the original page you are taken to when you get passed the login screen, but that has been an issue before implementing this.

Comment: Thats what I am talking about. Your fab button will be visible only when you select the page from drawer. It will not be visible if you are pressing back button in settings page. Try the solution which I mentioned. It will help you a lot and also optimize the app for better performance. In your solution you have lots of unnecessary object creation that will eventually slow down your app too.

Comment: Well currently the back button takes me to the login screen, so I would need to fix that.

Comment: In that case you need to add more condition checks in `onBackPressed()` method

Comment: `public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }`

Comment: yes, you need to make else if ladder to check
<pre>
1. Drawer is open or not
2. Settings page is open or not
3. Should you go back to login screen or not
</pre>
or you can use backstack to control the back press (not recommended in your case)